# Stylesheet linking not working

Tags: html, css

I am unable to link my CSS stylesheets:

Hierarchy:

index.html:

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="blue">Hello</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css:

```
// index.css
.blue {
  font:blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the console or network tabs?

Comment: If index.css is in the css folder and the css folder is in the same directory as index.html, then I see no problem with your stylesheet link.

Comment: Yeah the issue was not in the code itself.. it was my backend framework.

Comment: Then please delete the question.

Answer (score 7):

The "font" property isn't correct.

Try to replace this :

```
.blue {
  font:blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

By this :

```
.blue {
  color:blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

The css path seems correct, you can check on the network tab of your browser console, if you get a HTTP 200 the file is loaded, if 404 it's not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try the w3 css validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ 
I had a similar problem and it said there was a Chinese character in the css file but the file looked fine in notepad and elsewhere. Using BabelPad http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelPad.html I found the encoding of that file was UTF16LE. I changed the encoding to UTF8 and it worked fine.